# Can't get element from a jQuery plugin with method

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to create a small jQuery plugin that make an element foldable or unfoldable.

Basically, the plugin requires the dom element to have a title and a content :

```
<div class="foldable">
    <div class="foldable-title">Title</div>
    <div class="foldable-content">Content</div>
</div>
```

When the user clicks on the title, it should show or hide the content. This should works even when nested foldable elements are in the DOM

My plugin works as expected, when I click on the title it behaves as expected.

However, I want to be able to add "methods" to my plugin, but it does not works.

I have no error in the console, and simply nothing occurs.

Here is one of my methods:

```
    foldall: function () {
        $(this).each(function () {
            $(this).find(".foldable-unfolded").addClass("foldable-folded").removeClass("foldable-unfolded");
        });

        return this;
    }
```

I guess my issue comes from the `this` object. I'm not sure if its value is the expected one. It's provided using the following pattern:

```
$.fn.foldable = function (methodOrOptions) {
    if (methods[methodOrOptions]) {
        return methods[methodOrOptions].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
    } else if (typeof methodOrOptions === 'object' || !methodOrOptions) {
        // Default to "init"
        return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
    } else {
        $.error('Method ' + methodOrOptions + ' does not exist on jQuery.foldable');
    }
};
```

Any clue how to fix my issue?

FYI, a [jsFiddle is available with my current work](http://jsfiddle.net/stevebeauge/xCxEq/).

Here is its full code:

```
(function ($) {
    var methods = {
        init: function (options) {
            var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.foldable.defaults, options);
            this.each(function () {

                var $this = $(this);
                var $title = $this.find(opts.title).first();
                var $content = $this.find(opts.content).first();

                $this.data("foldable", opts);

                $title.css("cursor", "pointer");
                if (!$this.hasClass(opts.foldedClass) && !$this.hasClass(opts.unfoldedClass)) {
                    $this.addClass(opts.unfoldedClass);
                    //$content.hide();
                }
                $title.click(function () {
                    $content.slideToggle(function () {
                        $this.toggleClass(opts.unfoldedClass).toggleClass(opts.foldedClass);
                        if (opts.complete) opts.complete();
                    });
                });
            });
            return this;
        },
        foldall: function () {
            $(this).each(function () {
                $(this).find(".foldable-unfolded").andSelf().addClass("foldable-folded").removeClass("foldable-unfolded");
            });

            return this;
        },
        unfoldall: function () {
            $(this).each(function () {
                $(this).find(".foldable-folded").andSelf().addClass("foldable-unfolded").removeClass("foldable-folded");
            });
            return this;
        }
    };

    $.fn.foldable = function (methodOrOptions) {
        if (methods[methodOrOptions]) {
            return methods[methodOrOptions].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof methodOrOptions === 'object' || !methodOrOptions) {
            // Default to "init"
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + methodOrOptions + ' does not exist on jQuery.foldable');
        }
    };

    $.fn.foldable.defaults = {
        title: ".foldable-title",
        content: ".foldable-content",
        foldedClass: "foldable-folded",
        unfoldedClass: "foldable-unfolded",
        complete: null
    };

    var foldable = $(".foldable").foldable();

    $(".foldall").click(function () {
        foldable.foldable("foldall");
    });
    $(".unfoldall").click(function () {
        foldable.foldable("unfoldall");
    });
})(jQuery);
```

And few css rules:

```
.folded > .content {
    display:none;
}
.unfolded > .content {
    display:inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes simple things are the less obvious.

My issue was due a type in the css rules, specifically the class name. it should have been:

```
.foldable-folded > .foldable-content {
    display:none;
}
.foldable-unfolded > .foldable-content {
    display:inherit;
}
```